# Why does the smoothscroll not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I am wondering why does the smoothscroll doesn't work in my current project. I am using this in previous projects but this time on my current project it doesn't work. Does anyone of you knows why it doesn't work ?

html anchors has an Id and also it scales when its hovered.

Here is the JS

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Java != Javascript

Comment: You're currently finding the target by looking for a matching `name` attribute, not an `id` attribute. Try changing `[name=` to `[id=`.

Comment: I've tried it id doesn't work.

Comment: the div is scaling when it hovers. doest it have to do with that ?

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/vg9jk3k4/1/ can you create an example where this does not work? Also what part of this doesn't work? Be more detailed, what happens when you click?

Comment: Does your code respond to the click at all? What if you `console.log()` something inside the callback?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this code responds to the click, but in the case it doesn't, this is a very common problem for people who are starting with jQuery. This is what the following code does:

```
$(function() {
  ...
});
```

It means: run the following when the page starts.

Inside of that, this is what the following code does:

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
  ...
});
```

This means: find the element specified, and then execute the following code on click. In other words: find the element and attach an event handler to it. But keep in mind that this order "find the element" is run on page load.

This assumes that the elements you expect to react to it exist when the code is run, in this case, presumably, when the page is loaded.

But often, these days, this is not the case. You may import some data from JSON and transform it into links. In that case, the links won't exist when the page is loaded. A naive way to deal with it is to add the event handlers later. That's bad for several reasons:

- First of all, you have to add the event handlers each time you load the JSON, that's wasteful and it's a confusing workflow.
- You are not setting your links all in one place.
- You add plenty of events handlers when, ideally, one would be better. It would use fewer resources.

Fortunately, you only need to set one, and you can set it when the page loads. All you need to do is attach it to anything that will contain your target elements that exists when the page is loaded. I'm going to use `body` as an example, but it can be *anything* as long as

- it's an ancestor of your target elements and
- it exists when the function that specifies it is run.

Here's my example:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])', function() {
  ...
});
```

This means: find `body` (which necessarily exists when the page is loaded) and when it gets a click, run this, but only when the click was more specifically on *this* descendent: `'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])'`.

There's only one handler. It's set on page load. It will work with all future links, no matter how many times you change them within the lifetime of the page.

Comment: thank you for answering. I've already figure it out. there a problem on the css that I compiled from an old website.